# Lebesgue integration in one variable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

I have studying the conditions for the existence of the Lebesgue integral.

Generally, to show that existence of the integral of a function on an unbounded interval, one can integrate and take limits. If the integral is finite we can say the integral exists. But sometimes it can be difficult to evaluate the integral

The notes that I am following makes use of Upper and lower bounds of functions to show an integral exists.

I.e. $$\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\ln^\alpha(x)}{(x-1)^\beta} $$ exists if $\alpha <1$ and $\beta < 1$.

It is not very clear on how to do this for arbitrary integrals. Could someone please explain how to prove the existence of an integral with out having to compute the indefinite integral ? Any reference text name would also be appreciated. Thank you.

P.S : post has been made from a mobile device, hence typos are possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usually reduce to known form; specifically, if $f \sim g$, then $\int f$ exists if and only if $\int g$ does.

For example, since you know that

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^\alpha}$$ converges if and only if $\alpha > 1$,

then $\int_{1}^\infty \frac{x}{x^4 + 19}$ converges too  because it is asymptotic to $\frac{1}{x^3}$ which converges.

There are a variety of tests you can use, for example if $f < g$ then $\int g$ exists $\implies \int f$ exists, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. Could you suggest a good text ? Also, what happens in the case of more then one variable ? Thank you.

Comment: Any text on real analysis covers this topic.. Rudin is quite used, for example.